# Where do I set the following Apache directive? Header unset Accept-Ranges

Tags: apache-2.2

Sorry if this is a basic question, but when I searched for the answer, nothing really seemed to tell me precisely where to put this directive in Apache2 (I'm dealing with a 416 Range Request error).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_headers.html#header) say "server config, virtual host, directory, .htaccess". So, anywhere you need it.

Comment: I saw that....so server config would be httpd.conf?  The vhost would be 000-default under sites enabled and the directory is the part of the vhost directive you put it in?  Would it go in all or one of these files?

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/directive-dict.html#Context